# Why transaction to ERC20 token smart contract causes error?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I pushed this contract

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2#code

I want to issue test ERC20 token. But when I try to send ETH to my contract I see error.

What I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This contract doesn't appear to implement a fallback function that accepts ether, so the transaction gets reverted.

If you want your contract to do something when sent ether, implement a payable fallback function:

```
function() external payable {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I forgot about this!